# Google Places/Maps - any way to deduce the environment type of a location? E.g. near a beach, mountain, etc)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Probably an obscure question, but worth asking anyway -

I know Google Places can tell if the user is near a certain city-based location, such as a park or gym, but is there a way (with or without Google's APIs) to deduce that a user is near such a feature as a 'mountain' or 'beach'? Not a specific one, just 'a' beach.

Even just a map of environment types somehow linked to lat/long bounds would be useful - e.g. 'desert', 'forest' etc. Sometimes, Google has a listing of such a place, but it's wildly imprecise - for example, within the 'park' category of Places, I can find nature reserves, national parks, protected areas (with beaches or mountains!), or even just that corner memorial park in the local town. Is there any way to be more specific than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use natural_feature [type.](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table2) This type might return beaches or mountains.

If that doesn't work, you can use open street maps and use the [tag](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:natural%3Dbeach) feature.